# Max HTTP POST request size for Amazon S3 Browser-based upload?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, http-post

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html), the 'file' field name on a HTML POST for a browser-based upload can be a file or text content.  I'm interested in going the route of sending text, but would like to know exactly how much text I can send. I've read that the common server-based HTTP POST limit is 10M, but I'd like to know if there is any Amazon-specific documentation on the subject.

I guess my 1st question is really... Would the upload request size allowance be different for a text area submission than it is for a file submission (currently 5GB?) ?

If that answer is 'yes', then I would definitely want to know what the request size allowance would be for the text area submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs here (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) say this:

Content length rule, which checks that the size of an uploaded file is between a given minimum and maximum value. If this rule is not included in a policy document, users will be able to upload files of any size up to the 5GB limit imposed by S3.

I dont know how up to date these docs are.

Comment: I've read those docs, but I wasn't sure if the allowed file size also applied to uploading text content.  I guess the allowed content length of the POST request applies to both scenarios?

Comment: That would be my assumption.  But just like anything, I say try to test the upper limit and see if it is brittle at the same threshold.